# How to solve 'Badly constructed integrity constraints' in doctrine

Tags: doctrine

When I execute the command './doctrine build-all-reload'

It comes out the following output:

> build-all-reload - Are you sure you wish to drop your databases? (y/n) y
>
> build-all-reload - Successfully dropped database for connection named 'doctrine'
>
> build-all-reload - Generated models
>   successfully from YAML schema
>
> build-all-reload - Successfully
>   created database for connection named
>   'doctrine'
>
> Badly constructed integrity
>   constraints. Cannot define constraint
>   of different f ields in the same
>   table.

Here is the source code of Doctrine that outputs the error: [here](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/attachment/ticket/1691/fk_names.patch)

What causes the error? How can I debug where the error comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the code of either your YAML File or - if you wrote them yourself - your Models? That's where the problem should be.

Comment: ok thanks, I found the error. It is concerning the creation order of tables